# Reference String Resource in a custom file and Show autocomplete popup dialog to select when typing something like @string

Tags: android, xml

What I am want to do is the same as this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659412/reference-string-resource-in-custom-xml-resource).

The question could be divided into two-part.

First, Referencing to string in a custom XML file, thanks to the author of the question I mentioned above, this is solved.

Second, and is what I am asked, **How to show an autocomplete popup dialog to select string when typing string like @string**.

The [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35659412/reference-string-resource-in-custom-xml-resource) I mentioned has been asked about four years ago and I think the second part of the question is also need to solve, without autocomplete, typing string is so unbearable.

I try to do like [XSD - Autocomplete and Validate XML in IDE](https://metamug.com/article/xml/auto-complete-xml-editor-with-xsd-and-validations.html), but I failed.

Answer (score 0):

I have made it.

Roughly speaking, Create a schema of the XML and apply it. With a schema, the IDE could know your XML file structure and then give the popup dialog to show available options.

If you are newer at schema, don't afraid, because it is easy to understand and we could use  Android Studio to generate it.

How to generate a schema file?

First, select your XML file, then key `ctrl` + `shift` + `A` to show the actions input dialog. Key in "Generate" you will find the action of `Generate XSD file from XML file ...`, magically a schema for your XML will be created for you.

And then apply it to your XML, and how?

I think I don't have to show the concrete steps since it's unnecessary. (Probably it may be nobody to see it and I write here mainly leave a note for me)

I encounter the biggest problem is how to define the restriction for the attribute. how I make it?

In my Gradle task, I use the [java parser](https://javaparser.org/) parser the file of R.java and get a list of String then create `.xsd` file to create a restriction type. Then, in the main '.xsd' file, include it, and apply the type to the attribute.

```
  // file: cartype.xml  our target
  <Car>
      <item boxId="1"  bandName="@string/xxx"  ... />
  </Car>


  // define a type for the attriute of bandName and tell what can be select
  <xs:simpleType name="AndroidStringType">
    <xs:restriction >
      <xs:enumeration value="1" />
      <xs:enumeration value="2" />
      <xs:enumeration value="3" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:complexType name="itemType">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="boxId"/>
        // apply the type to the attribute
        <xs:attribute type="AndroidStringType" name="bandName"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```